# Not understanding group/value/capture attributes of Powershell object matches method

Tags: regex, powershell, object, match

Because of my lack of understanding of Powershell objects my question may not be worded accurately. I take it from the documentation [Powershell 7.3 ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3) that I am using a script block & utilizing the Powershell automatic variable `$_` But that is about as relevant to my example that these docs get.

I'm trying to access each of two parts of a collection of text file type name/address listings. Namely the first three listings (001 - 003) or the second three (004 - 006)

Using `$regexListings` and `$testListings` I have tested that I can access, the first three or second three listings, using references to the capture groups e.g `$1 $2` See this example running here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bQiCj1/1)

When I run the following Powershell code:

```
$regexListings = '(?s)(001.*?003.*?$)|(004.*?006.*?$)'

$testListings = 
'001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street 
002 BROWN James 101 Browns Road 
003 BROWN Jemmima 101 Browns Road
004 BROWN John 101 Browns Road 
005 CAMPBELL Colin 57 Camp Avenue
006 DONNAGAN Dolores 11 Main Road'

$testListings | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexListings | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches}
```

Output is:

```
Groups    : {0, 1, 2}
Success   : True
Name      : 0
Captures  : {0}
Index     : 0
Length    : 204
Value     : 001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street
            002 BROWN James 101 Browns Road
            003 BROWN Jemmima 101 Browns Road
            004 BROWN John 101 Browns Road
            005 CAMPBELL Colin 57 Camp Avenue
            006 DONNAGAN Dolores 11 Main Road
ValueSpan :
```

My interpretation of the Powershell output is:

- there are 3 match groups?
- no captures available
- the value is all of it?

Why does the Powershell script output `Captures {0}` when the link page (regex101) above describes two capture groups which I can access?

The documentation [Groups, Captures, and Substitutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3) is helpful but doesn't address this kind of issue. I have gone on using trial & error examples like:

```
ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups}
ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Captures}
ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

And I'm still none the wiser.

Comment: Have you tried the regex with `(?ms)` instead of just `(?s)`?

Comment: What you suggest does the following according to regex101: "multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)" My regex is only using end of string `$` so this suggestion makes no difference that I can see.

Comment: I though `003.*?$` was supposed to match just to the end of the line starting with `003` rather than to the end of the whole string.

Comment: Your suggestion made no difference using regex101 editor. But it changes the Powershell output. So I guess there is a difference in behavior to be considered.

Comment: Thank you @jkiiski Your multiline modifier made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Information overflow. What's being output is what's relevant to us, the administrators. Capture group `0` is the entire value since `$regexListings` indeed matches the entire string. This is where PowerShell attempts to be helpful with it's rich *type* system and displays what we may find useful; *although, this may just be the implementation of the creators of the cmdlet*. So, you were on the right track with `$_.Matches.Groups` which should've exposed the capture groups and the values for the RegEx matching.

If you're looking to access those values, as mentioned above, you'd have to iterate over `.Matches.Groups` within that `Foreach-Object`. What you're passing isn't the individual captures to that cmdlet, but rather the captures of the expression as a whole. This is why you're better off saving to a variable and indexing through the group capture(s) such as: `$var.Matches.Groups[0]`, or `$var.Matches.Groups[1]`, etc.. You can also just use the automatic variable `$matches` to get some confusion out the way seeing as it's populated via the `-Match` operator, you can index through the captures with `$matches[n]` instead. Using your same example:

```
$regexListings = '(?s)(001.*?003.*?$)|(004.*?006.*?$)'

$testListings = 
'001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street 
002 BROWN James 101 Browns Road 
003 BROWN Jemmima 101 Browns Road
004 BROWN John 101 Browns Road 
005 CAMPBELL Colin 57 Camp Avenue
006 DONNAGAN Dolores 11 Main Road'

$testListings -match $regexListings 
$Matches
```

Which outputs:

```
True # this is output by -match letting you know it's succeeded in matching.

Name                           Value                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                            
1                              001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street ...                                              
0                              001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street ...
```

Now you have a hashtable with a more *representable* example of the pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access each of two parts of the listings I needed to be able to see them in the output using:

```
$regexListings = '(?ms)(001.*?003.*?$)|(004.*?006.*?$)'

$testListings | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexListings | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Captures}


Groups    : {0, 1, 2}
Success   : True
Name      : 0
Captures  : {0}
Index     : 0
Length    : 102
Value     : 001 AALTON Alan 25 Every Street
            002 BROWN James 101 Browns Road
            003 BROWN Jemmima 101 Browns Road
ValueSpan : 

Groups    : {0, 1, 2}
Success   : True
Name      : 0
Captures  : {0}
Index     : 103
Length    : 101
Value     : 004 BROWN John 101 Browns Road
            005 CAMPBELL Colin 57 Camp Avenue
            006 DONNAGAN Dolores 11 Main Road
ValueSpan :
```

The differences from the question code being:

- using multi line modifier `(?ms)` instead of `(?s)` in the regex
- using `{$_.Matches.Captures}` as the regex contains capture grouping

Access to these captures can be got from assigning a variable then indexing e.g:

```
$result = $testListings | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexListings | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Captures}
$result[1]
$result[0]
```